# Entity Framework 6 Code first - Nested entity calculations very slow

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to return calculated values with an entity model when retrieving from the database. For example -

```
public class PaymentCertificate : DBModelBase
{
    public PaymentCertificate()
    {
        ValuationItems = new Collection<ValuationItem>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<ValuationItem> ValuationItems { get; set; }
}

public class ValuationItem: DBModelBase
{
    public virtual Cost Cost { get; set; }
    public decimal ValuationQuantity { get; set; }
}

public class Cost: DBModelBase
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

When I return say a few hundred PaymentCertificate models from the database I want to calculate the Total for each so currently I am using a loop e.g.

```
foreach (var cert in PaymentCertificateList)
{
    var total = PaymentCertificateList
        .Sum(x => x.ValuationItems.ValuationQuantity*x.ValuationItems.Cost.Price);
}
```

This is really slow when calculating a few hundred payment certificates and I believe it's because of the calculation with nested entities (and even slower when using automapper). How can I 'preload' the Total value when returning the certificate object from the database? I'm thinking this is the best option as to push the calculation to the database side. Is this possible? Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Show us how you are populating PaymentCertificateList.

Comment: what about having a calculated 'Total' field in the table itself?

Comment: I don't really wanted a calculated total column in the table as this would need to be updated if the Price changed at any point. It needs to be dynamically calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you are lazy loading the referenced tables, it will query the database for each call in the loop.  You can avoid this by eagerly loading the related entities using .Include.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Adding onto that, you can also use projection to do some of the calculations in the initial query.  I am not sure if this will work for your situation as you did not post any of your initial queries.

Looking at your model you could do something like this to get all the totals

```
var totals = DbContext.PaymentCertificates
                .Include("ValuationItems.Cost")
                .Select(c => new {
                    Total = c.ValuationItems.Sum(x => x.Cost.Price*x.ValuationQuantity)
                });
```

Comment: Initial query is a simple select from DB Dbcontext.PaymentCertificates.ToList(). I am lazy loading my related entities through the virtual keyword

Comment: The initial query is a simple select - DbContext.PaymentCertificates.ToList() I am lazy loading my related entities using the virtual keyword. Is this what is causing the slowness. Will it be much quicker if I eager load the entities ?

Comment: @JamesDev `virtual` makes them **lazy loaded**, but you're trying to do something with them immediately, so you might as well eager load them. But your `ToList()` will materialize it, so you should be fine on that front.

Comment: you can add the .Include(c => c.ValuationItems) in your initial query to tell EF to grab those linked entities in the initial query.  If you run a sql profiler when your code executes, you will be able to see the difference with and without using Include.  I have found express profiler to be very handy (and it's free) https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property to return this for you for each:

```
 public class PaymentCertificate : DBModelBase
 {
     public PaymentCertificate()
     {
         ValuationItems = new Collection();
     }
     public virtual ICollection ValuationItems { get; set; }

     [NotMapped]
     public decimal Total { get {return ValuationItems.Sum(v => v.ValuationQuantity * v.Cost.Price); }; private set;}
 }
```

The `NotMapped` attribute means EF will ignore it.

Comment: I have tried this option but it yields the same results as doing it in my example above. Same slow times.